# How to use (*mpORBextractorLeft)(im,cv::Mat(),mvKeys,mDescriptors);

Tags: c++, orb

```
void Frame::ExtractORB(int flag, const cv::Mat &im)
{
    if(flag==0)
        (*mpORBextractorLeft)(im,cv::Mat(),mvKeys,mDescriptors);
    else
        (*mpORBextractorRight)(im,cv::Mat(),mvKeysRight,mDescriptorsRight);
}
```

How to use like this format? 
(*name)(param1, param2, param3, param4)

this code is belong to orb_slam ....
https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2

Comment: It's a pointer to a function that you can invoke as in your example code. When you've read about its syntax a bit, you might want to sharpen the wording of you question a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think Function points are known to put return types in front of sentences. Is it possible to omit void?

Answer (score 1):

A declaration of a pointer to a non-member function has the following structure:

return-type (* name)(argument-list)

So in order to declare a pointer `func`to a function taking a `const char*` and an `int`as an argument and returning `bool` you say

```
bool (*func)(const char*, int);
```

Note, that you need the parenthesis around the `*func`, because otherwise the compiler would interpret it as a declaration of function

```
bool* func(const char*, int);
```

returning `bool*`.

Assume now, that you have a function

```
bool foo(const char* x, int y) { /* ... */ }
```

of corresponding type, then you can make your pointer point to this function by

```
func = &foo;
```

In order to invoke the function pointed to by `func`, you dereference the pointer and invoke it with the arguments like this

```
bool result = (*func)("abc", 3);
```

This is what you are doing in the example you provided. Calling the function pointed to by `mpORBextractorLeft` (resp. `mpORBextractorRight`) with the given arguments.

---

Some further notes:

- Dereferencing of the function pointer may be omitted, so

  ```
  bool result = func("abc", 3);
  ```

  should work as well.
- When declaring the pointer, it can be initialized immediately:

  ```
  bool (*func)(const char*, int) = &foo;
  ```
- A `typedef` can be used to simplify code if you need to write the type of the pointer multiple times:

  ```
  typedef bool (*fun_ptr)(const char*, int);
  fun_ptr func1 = &foo;
  fun_ptr func2 = &bar;
  ```